# How to build packages for Maverick while running Lucid?

Tags: packaging, debootstrap, chroot

I would like to be able to build a package for the Maverick distribution release of Ubuntu, while running the Lucid distribution release.

I found this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot which seems to explain what I would like to do. However, the instructions say to go to a specific website (the link is in the article, I can't post more than one link) and download the debootstrap package that has the first word of the distribution relase appended (eg. "maverick"), but no such package exists.

What do I do?

Comment: For Maverick: http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/debootstrap. See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot.

Answer (score 4):

Many developers use [pbuilder](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pbuilder)
 for this task. There is a very [comprehensive guide to pbuilder on the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto). You might also look into the `pbuilder-dist` script. It is a is a wrapper that makes it easy to use pbuilder with many different versions of Ubuntu and/or Debian. It is available in the [ubuntu-dev-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-dev-tools) package.

```
sudo apt-get install pbuilder ubuntu-dev-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

The `debootstrap` program is available in the lucid package repositories.  You can just install it using your favourite package manager.

If you really wanted to fetch the .deb and install it by hand, it's at
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/debootstrap/debootstrap_1.0.25~lucid1_all.deb